# How to align both right and left axis in the same line using ios-charts?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have the following line chart with 2 datasets.
One data set is dependent on the left yAxis the other one on the right yAxis.

Now i want them both to have the zero value in the same line.
The other values are ok to not be aligned. 
How can i do that?

Code:

```
    let speedLine = LineChartDataSet(values: speedEntries, label: "Speed")
    speedLine.colors = [UIColor.white]
    speedLine.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    speedLine.axisDependency = .left

    let powerLine = LineChartDataSet(values: powerEntries, label: "Power")
    powerLine.colors = [UIColor.green]
    powerLine.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    powerLine.axisDependency = .right

    let data = LineChartData()
    data.addDataSet(speedLine)
    data.addDataSet(powerLine)

    chartView.data = data
    chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    chartView.xAxis.labelCount = 20
    chartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    chartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.green
    chartView.legend.textColor = UIColor.white
    chartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = -80.0

    chartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code? Then It will be possible to reproduce the problem

Comment: @DevB2F done, added the code to the question

Answer (score 1):

Since you have:

```
chartView.rightAxis.axisMinimum = -80.0
```

You might need to do this as well:

```
chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = -80.0
```

Comment: Didnt work. I tried removing both, adding both. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think there is still no resolution for this problem but we can still hide yAxis right side.

```
let yAxisLeft = chartView.leftAxis
yAxisLeft.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
yAxisLeft.gridColor = UIColor(hex: "DCE5EE")
yAxisLeft.labelFont = Theme.Font.main(ofSize: 9, weight: .regular)
yAxisLeft.labelXOffset = 2
yAxisLeft.labelTextColor = Theme.Color.white
yAxisLeft.axisLineColor = UIColor(hex: "DCE5EE")
yAxisLeft.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
yAxisLeft.labelCount = 4
yAxisLeft.axisMinLabels = 1
yAxisLeft.enabled = true
yAxisLeft.axisMinimum = 0

let yAxisRight = chartView.rightAxis
yAxisRight.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
yAxisRight.labelFont = Theme.Font.main(ofSize: 9, weight: .regular)
yAxisRight.labelXOffset = -2
yAxisRight.labelTextColor = Theme.Color.white
yAxisRight.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
yAxisRight.labelCount = 4
yAxisRight.axisMinLabels = 1
yAxisRight.enabled = true
yAxisRight.axisMinimum = 0
```

This is the final result:

[image: Print screen of the chart]